# Selenium Webdriver saving corrupt jpeg

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

Below is a script that opens a URL, saves the image as a JPEG file, and also saves some html attribute (i.e. the Accession Number) as the file name. The script runs but saves corrupted images; size = 210 bytes with no preview. When I try to open them, the error message suggests the file is damaged.

The reason I am saving the images instead of doing a direct request is to get around the site's security measures, it doesn't seem to allow web scraping. My colleague who tested the script on Windows below got a robot check request (just once at the beginning of the loop) before the images successfully downloaded. I do not get this check from the site, so I believe my script is actually pulling the robot check instead of the webpage as it hasn't allowed me to manually bypass the check. I'd appreciate help addressing this issue, perhaps forcing the robot check when the script opens the first URL.

**Dependencies**
I am using Python 3.6 on MacOS. If anyone testing this for me is also using Mac and is using Selenium for the first time, please note that a file called "Install Certificates.command" first needs to be executed before you can access anything. Otherwise, it will throw a "Certificate_Verify_Failed" error. Easy to search in Finder.

Download for Selenium ChromeDriver utilized below: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.41/

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib
import time

urls = ['https://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/483452',
        'https://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/460833',
        'https://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/551844']

#Set up Selenium Webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--test-type")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/user/Desktop/chromedriver", chrome_options=options)


for link in urls:
    #Load page and pull HTML File

    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

    #Find details (e.g. Accession Number)
    details = soup.find_all('dl', attrs={'class':'artwork__tombstone--row'})
    for d in details:
        if 'Accession Number' in d.find('dt').text:
            acc_no = d.find('dd').text

    pic_link = soup.find('img', attrs={'id':'artwork__image', 'class':'artwork__image'})['src']
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(pic_link, '/Users/user/Desktop/images/{}.jpg'.format(acc_no))

    time.sleep(2)
```